# Attempting to change the colour of one link without a colour without the option

Tags: layout, colors, hyperlink, tumblr

So I have been attempting different variations of trying to use #dc6820 in my code to change only one link source for a layout I'm helping someone with. Usually, I don't have too much trouble, but no matter what I've tried, it just remains the same (or I muck up the coding and have to redo it)

This is the section I'm attempting to change:

```
< div id="info" >
< br >posted < a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}< /a> {block:RebloggedFrom} 

**via < a href="     {ReblogParentURL}">{ReblogParentName}< /a>{/block:RebloggedFrom}   
{block:ContentSource}(< a     href="{SourceURL}">© < a href="{SourceURL}">{SourceLink}< 
/a>){/block:ContentSource}    {block:RebloggedFrom} < a href="{ReblogParentURL}" 
target="_#nk">< /a>{/block:RebloggedFrom}**

with < a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}< /a>
{block:HasTags}< div id="tags">♡{block:Tags} #< a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}< /a>    
{/block:Tags}< /div>{/block:HasTags}</div></div>
{/block:Posts}
{block:PostNotes}< div id="notes">{PostNotes}</div>{/block:PostNotes}
{/block:Posts}</div></div></div>

< /div>
```

I'm attempting to change the section between asterisks (via --> /block:RebloggedFrom}

Edit// I've attempted the style change referenced below to, unfortunately, no results :(

Here's a link to the pastebin with the section (hopefully) without the errors pastebin.com/qNAbZAhQ –

Comment: Well, first of all, I see at least one unclosed anchor tag that might be causing you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's clean-up that HTML and make sure our tags are closed.

**HTML**

```
<div id="info">
    {block:Date}
      posted <a class="time" href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}</a>
    {/block:Date}
    {block:RebloggedFrom} 
      via <a class="reblog" href="{ReblogParentURL}">{ReblogParentName}</a>
    {/block:RebloggedFrom}   
    {block:ContentSource}
      (<a class="source" href="{SourceURL}">© {SourceTitle}</a>)
    {/block:ContentSource}
    {block:NoteCount}
      with <a class="notes" href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>
    {/block:NoteCount}
    {block:HasTags}
      <div id="tags">
        ♡
        {block:Tags}
          #<a class="tag" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>    
        {/block:Tags}
      </div>
    {/block:HasTags}
</div>
```

As you can see, in addition to closing tags (and removing unnecessary elements) and wrapping everything in its correct block, I added different `class` attributes to each type of link so that you can go into the stylesheet in the `head` and add your colors. For example...

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    a.reblog {
        color: #DC6820;
    }
</style>
```

or

```
<style type="text/css">
    .reblog {
        color: #DC6820;
    }
</style>
```

or even

```
<style type="text/css">
    .reblog:link {
        color: #DC6820;
    }
</style>
```

That latter would allow you to use CSS state selectors to change the color of the link depending on the state of the link, e.g. active, hover, visited.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style attribute to your a tag as such

```
< a href="     {ReblogParentURL}" style="color: #dc6820;">
```

Of course you need to add this to all your a tags that you want to change.

Comment: While that inline style works, I think using a CSS class would be the easier method.

Comment: Yeah, however I don't know if one can access the CSS at Tumblr (the question is tagged with it) so I just answered with something that I know work with the available information.

Comment: It is available. Also, there's some errors in their code that might be causing the problem in the first place.

Comment: The style attribute didn't work even as I placed it in all the sections. :( Here's a link to the pastebin with the section without the errors http://pastebin.com/qNAbZAhQ